# Scala Play Framework form binding as Map[String, Double]

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am stuck on a very simple problem : 
Using Play framework and Scala, I would like to create a form which is just basically going to map my request to a Map[String, Double] :

```
 val repartitionForm = Form(
tuple(
  "date" -> date,
  "map" -> ???
))
```

The json I receive is of following format :

```
{"date":"yyyymmdd","map":{"key": 12.3, "anotherKey" : 89.3}}
```

I would like to add that those keys are dynamic thus not known in advance.

Is it possible ? If no could you give me some hints on how I could achieve this ?

Thanks for you help

Comment: Are you looking for a form that maps dynamic fields or how to map dynamic keys from JSON blobs?

Comment: Play expects functions from tuple of unpacked fields to your map, and from your map to option of tuple, so you can just provide it, but it seems like a bit of boilerplate, I don't know a simple solution to get a map, maybe there is one. What you could also do is make a case class with meaningful name and fields, and pass there apply/unapply methods.

Comment: I have updated my question so it's more clear ! @Łukasz, I have a case class but I don't know deserialize my map into it !

Comment: So if you want to bind map from form field you need 'FieldMapping[Map[String, Double]]` that can be created with Forms.of[T] method, with implicit Formatter[T] in scope. You need to implement this formatter for a map. For examples check play.api.data.format.Format.scala

Comment: Thanks for your answer Łukasz, I was thinking of doing this. Also, since it's a Forms.of[T] returns a field mapping, it's impossible to set it at root level :( It's surprising that such feature is not provided out of the box. Also I want to highlight that it may not be so surprising since it's a "form" validation util and in a Form, all the fields are supposed to be known.